# paypal keys in version control

Tags: security, paypal

What are the security implications of storing your keys (`app_cert.pem`,`app_key.pem`, `paypal.pem`), which are used to encrypt/sign your paypal transactions, in VCS? I'm thinking that someone who has the certificate and my database primary key will be able to mark a purchase as paid. That's the worst that can happen, right?

Comment: Just thought that this is more appropriate for security.stackexchange.com. Can someone move it, please?

Comment: I don't know about that.  Secure development practices are sorely needed in the industry, and this site has plenty of questions related to security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest danger is in who has access to the source control.  If the developers that have access to the source control are already allowed to have acccess to the keys, then there is no additional risk ***as long as the source control is locked down so that only authorized users have access***.

If you allow anonymous read access to the repository, then someone else can get your keys, which may be helpful to a dedicated attacker.  Perhaps they'll know how to do something with it that we wouldn't think of.

**Never underestimate the ingenuity of someone who has the skill  and the lack of scruples, and the motivation of an easy payday.**

Personally, I wouldn't put them in source control.  I'd  protect them as if they were my own SSN and bank info.

Even if your repo is locked down tight now, you don't know what will change in the future.  It would be too easy for some future developer to start collaborating with an outside vendor, for example, and grant read-only access, not thinking that they're exposing such sensitive info.

Comment: The repo has private access (and will be so). But I think you're thinking about it in the right way: what if it were public and that malicious person person gets access to it. I'm trying to estimate the worst case. The alternative to storing it in VCS is to scp and put some access permissions on it. This would provide a more limited access, but it complicates deployment automation dramatically.